# Making ScrollView display the last visible view

Tags: android, scrollview

In my scrollview there is a relative layout, which contains EditTextView and Button, on button click 2nd EditTextView and 2nd Button will be made visible and so on till 5th EditTextView and Button. now how to display the last visible view (2nd button ) on the screen, right now its not being displayed, i need to scroll down to see it

Comment: And your exact question is? Of course if it doesn't fit in the screen you'll have to scroll... Please, provide some code & screenshots and try to explain yourself better.

Comment: thats what, if it doesnt fit the screen i need to scroll down. my question is, how can i make this scroll automatic?, so that the last visible view is displayed on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I think found the answer to your question.
First initialize your scroll View ( findViewById(int))
Then On a button Click write this code :

`scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);`

In my Activity:

```
public class SampleScrollviewActivity extends Activity  {
Button b1;
Button b2;
ScrollView scroll;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    b2=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    b1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    scroll=(ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrlView1);

    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

        }
    });
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_UP);
        }
    });
}
```

}

Hope This helps!

Answer (score 0):

My general approach to solve this problem would be - Find the location of ( 2nd button) using following code

```
View secondButton = findViewById(R.id.secondButtonID);
//Use getLocation on screen API to find exact location (2nd Button) View

int location[] = new int[2];
secondButton.getLocationOnScreen(location);
//Now you have X,Y location of second View on screen
int x = location[0];
int y = location[1];
ScrollView scrollView = findVieById(R.id.scrollViewID);
//Move to X,Y position
scrollView.scrollTo(x,y);  //you can add some offset eg. y +- offset
```